# Combining GMPXX and C++11 and later

Tags: c++, c++11, gmp, auto

I have minor problem when combining GMP and C++11.

Example program:

```
#include <gmpxx.h>

int main()
{
    mpz_class a,b; //ok
    auto c = a+b; //ok (?)
    c = 0; //error
}
```

Error message:

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are '__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __gmp_binary_expr<__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>, __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>, __gmp_binary_plus> >' and 'int')
     c = 0;
       ^
```

What's the problem?

Comment: `auto` does not play nicely with expression templates in this case.

Comment: have a look at https://herbsutter.com/2012/04/03/reader-qa/ which links to https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/inferring-too-much/

Comment: There is a paragraph titled "C++11" in GMP's documentation: https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Limitations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `operator+(mpz_class const&, mpz_class const&)` doesn't return another `mpz_class`, but an intermediate result type `__gmp_expr<T, U>`.

There are comments in the [source file](ftp://ftp.tku.edu.tw/NetBSD/NetBSD-current/src/external/lgpl3/gmp/dist/gmpxx.h)

> Results of operators and functions are instances of `__gmp_expr<T, U>`.
>
> ...
>
> Actual evaluation of a `__gmp_expr<T, U>` object is done when it gets
>   assigned to an `mp*_class` ("lazy" evaluation): this is done by calling
>   its eval() method.

As you use `auto c = a + b;` you get `c` is of the type `__gmp_expr<T, U>`, and therefore other `mp*_class` or integers are unable to assign to it.